# spring boot 2.1.5.RELEASE and GraphQL Failed to bind properties under 'graphiql.endpoint'

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I work with spring boot 2.1.5.RELEASE and I want to work with GraphQL.

In the pom.xml, I set GraphQL dependencies. The dependencies are resolved. I get an error when I start  the server.

The version of `graphql-spring-boot-starter is 5.10.0.`

I don't know how to solve the following issue.

This my pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pluralsight</groupId>
    <artifactId>fundamentals</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fundamentals</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.41</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is application.properties

```
graphql.servlet.mapping=/graphql
graphql.servlet.enabled=true
graphql.servlet.corsEnabled=true

graphiql.enabled=true
graphiql.endpoint=/graphql
graphiql.mapping=graphiql
```

I am not able to start my application, this is the error

```
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'graphiql.endpoint' to com.oembedler.moon.graphiql.boot.GraphiQLProperties$Endpoint
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.handleBindError(Binder.java:364) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:324) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$4(Binder.java:448) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:90) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:79) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:56) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:452) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:572) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:558) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.access$400(Binder.java:513) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:320) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:238) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:225) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:89) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:96) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.pluralsight.FundamentalsApplication.main(FundamentalsApplication.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.oembedler.moon.graphiql.boot.GraphiQLProperties$Endpoint]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter$CompositeConversionService.convert(BindConverter.java:170) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter.convert(BindConverter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter.convert(BindConverter.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindProperty(Binder.java:435) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:380) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:320) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 3):

If you check [graphql-spring-boot github README](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/blob/master/README.md), you'll find out the way to config your graphiql endpoint

for example like this:

```
graphiql:
    mapping: /graphiql
    endpoint:
      graphql: /graphql
      subscriptions: /subscriptions
    subscriptions:
      timeout: 30
      reconnect: false
    static:
      basePath: /
    enabled: true
    pageTitle: GraphiQL
    cdn:
        enabled: false
        version: 0.13.0
    props:
        resources:
            query: query.graphql
            defaultQuery: defaultQuery.graphql
            variables: variables.graphql
        variables:
            editorTheme: "solarized light"
    headers:
        Authorization: "Bearer <your-token>"
```

Since you're using `application.properties`, all you need to do is changing your properties into this:

```
graphiql.enabled=true
graphiql.endpoint.graphql=/graphql
graphiql.mapping=graphiql
```

By adding an extra `.graphql` behind `graphiql.endpoint` will fix this problem